# CRM Package deployer Tool - import file as attachment

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Does PackageDeployer utility support to import data as well as its related file(pdf etc.) as attachment into CRM?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, **Package deployer tool** is for [automation of CRM deployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647420.aspx), moving solutions + import flat files (also exported) between different environments. It uses **Configuration Migration tool** to move/import entity data.

> A “package” can consist of any or all of the following:
> •   One or more Dynamics 365 solution files.
> •   Flat files or exported data files from the Configuration Migration tool. For information about the Configuration Migration tool, see [Manage configuration data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647421.aspx).
> •   Custom code that can run during or after the package is deployed to Microsoft Dynamics 365.

Moreover Configuration Migration tool is meant for different purpose, as in:

> The Configuration Migration tool enables you to move configuration data across Microsoft Dynamics 365 instances and organizations. Configuration data is used to define custom functionality in Dynamics 365, and is typically stored in custom entities. Configuration data is different from end user data (account, contacts, and so on). A typical example of configuration data is what you define in Unified Service Desk for Microsoft Dynamics 365 to configure a customized call center agent application. The Unified Service Desk entities, along with the configuration data that is stored in the entities, define an agent application.
>
> **The Configuration Migration tool is primarily meant for migrating configuration data, not actual Dynamics 365 data.**

Now if you want to move some attachments, like the above 3rd bullet says - you can use custom code to do it (I never tried this).

**Notes (annotations)** which stores attachment files can be [migrated using scribe](https://www.powerobjects.com/2014/06/04/migrating-notes-via-scribe-failing-microsoft-dynamics/) alternatively. See other supported [choices](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/data-migration-and-integration/select-a-tool-to-use/).

Sometimes [document templates](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/document-templates-mover-crm-2016-crm-instances/) which is not part of solution, has to be moved separately using xrmtoolbox plugins.

Comment: I have already implemented custom code to attach files in deployer package and I just wanted to confirm that whether i am my approach is correct or not. 
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @yogs as I said in answer, custom code is fine. You are good.. :)